# How to generalize the infinite potential well to $n$ dimensions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation

A 1d infinite potential well admits the oscillating sinusoidal solutions.

How would one go about to set up the Schrodinger Equation for the $n$-dimensional infinite potential well and find solutions for it?

This may seem like a broad question. But I don't know how to start or think about it. A hint would also be appreciable if the question is too trivial.

My aim is to check the node theorem of energy eigenfunctions in higher dimensions.

We already know that for a 1d arbitrary potential the node theorem can be proved by exploiting the uniqueness of the Schrodinger Equation and the solutions of the 1d infinite potential well.

I am trying to see if similar arguments can be made for $n$-dimensional arbitrary potential with the help of the $n$-dimensional solutions of infinite potential well.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more detail about node theorem? And for the 3 dimension for example, you could take some infinite potential well that has quite different boundary. One dimensional case only considers the endpoint of intervals but in this case, boundary could be (0<=x,y,z<=a) or (r<=a), and it’s quite trivial that such different boundary condition leads to different solution even though they are considered to be the same kind of ‘infinite potential well’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unclear about the part of your motivation that deals with arbitrary potentials. But there are many $d$ dimensional generalizations of the infinite potential well. These are related to the co-ordinate systems (there are 13 if I recall) where Laplace's equation can be solved by separation of variables. The setup in one dimension is a potential which is zero in $[0, L]$ and infinite everywhere else. The eigenfunctions in your notes probably look like
\begin{align}
\psi_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \mathrm{sin}(n \pi x / L), \quad E_n = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{n^2 \pi^2}{L^2}.
\end{align}
Once we go to higher dimensions, we can instead consider a potential which is zero within an $L \times \dots \times L$ hypercube and infinite everywhere else. Then, it is a simple exercise to show that the above becomes
\begin{align}
\psi_{n_1, \dots, n_d}(x_1, \dots, x_d) = \prod_{i = 1}^d \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \sin(n_i \pi x_i / L), \quad E_{n_1, \dots n_d} = \frac{\hbar^2 \pi^2}{2mL^2} (n_1^2 + \dots + n_d^2).
\end{align}
Indeed, the 1d version is normalized and satisfies
\begin{equation}
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \psi_n(x) = E_n. \psi_n(x)
\end{equation}
Therefore, the more general version satisfies the higher dimensional Schroedinger equation
\begin{equation}
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left ( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2} + \dots + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_d^2} \right ) \psi = E\psi
\end{equation}
because $\psi_{n_1, \dots, n_d}(x_1, \dots, x_d) = \psi_{n_1}(x_1) \dots \psi_{n_d}(x_d)$, $E_{n_1, \dots, n_d} = E_{n_1} + \dots + E_{n_d}$ and each derivative only acts on one of the factors.

The boundary conditions mean the wavefunction has to vanish whenever one of the co-ordinates reaches a face of the hypercube. These all occur at $x_i = 0$ or $x_i = L$ so there is no conflict there. If we had a square where $x$ was confined to $[0, L]$ but $y$ was confined to $[-L/2, L/2]$ then we would need one sine and one cosine instead of all sines, etc.

Comment: Ok, I added the explicit eigenvalue equations. The fact that when two decoupled Schroedinger equations are added, their corresponding wavefunctions are multiplied is sure to come up a lot.